# User roles in route settings

Tags: security, symfony, controller, routes

To check if a user have access to a controller depending on his role we usually do something like this in the top of the controller:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

or use annotation:

```
/**
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
```

And all protected controllers have such a check.

Is it possible to put this check in a route settings, e. g. this way or somehow similar:

```
protected_route:
  path: /top_secret
  defaults: { _controller: '...', roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

?

Comment: I don't see the difference between those two ways..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should look at this page:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-url-patterns-access-control

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        # ...

    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Quite good variant, but IMO not so handy, because routes and their security settings are stored in different places. I wonder can we put role settings in routes.

Comment: And besides we have to use patterns instead of route names in security.yml.

Comment: I don't know the reason for splitting routes and security, but as far as I know this is the standard way. I generally try to split the routes for the main roles, like `/admin` for all pages that need the `ADMIN` role, then use some further (but rare) checking in the controllers.

Comment: @basilup: Dric512 is right. This is the symfonic way to do ;)

Comment: OK, thanks, it seems I have no another choice =) But it's quite weird IMO - I can place \@Route parameter to set a route as well as \@Security parameter to set roles in annotation, but in a router setting I can set just a route.

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of the external content in your answer rather than just a link. Cheers!

Comment: I use the \@route annotations above my controllermethods (actions). In case you use the \@security annotation too then you have them on the same place. Its the most friendly manner to store your routes too in my opinion. uhm Cheers SilverlightFox.